# Study of portals

Tags: general-topology, geometry, dynamical-systems

Mathematicians seem to dedicate some attention to problems relating to the game of billiards (see [Billiards](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Billiards.html), [Dynamical billiars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards), [Outer billiard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_billiard)).

Has anyone been studying a somewhat similar set of problems relating to portals (as described, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137999/what-is-the-topology-of-a-world-with-portals)), either in 3D or 2D? In particular, I’m interested in what happens when one tries to insert a portal into its complementary portal depending on the location and angle.

Comment: [Here is one place I've seen.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B19nlhbA7-E)

Comment: Also of interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q0sHf_n_2Y.

Comment: Interactive demo: https://optozorax.github.io/portal/?scene=portal_in_portal